# Reverse div order multiline

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, masonry

I'm trying to get the following result with CSS.

I want the first div to start at the bottom right. When adding a second div or third div, it needs to place itself needly next to the former div on the left side like so:

```
| div 3 | div 2 | div 1
```

Consider having a wrapper div that wraps the next div following divs (div 4, 5 , and 6). Normally the divs would go with the flow of the document and go under the first three divs. I want it the other way round like this:

```
                | div 7
| div 6 | div 5 | div 4
| div 3 | div 2 | div 1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel a bit dumb figuring out my own problem in minutes, while stumbling on this problem beforehand for hours, but I was looking over `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`. The wrap-reverse was important here. The outcome was actually pretty simple with the following code:

```
  .container {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid coral;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-content: end;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
```

Hope to help others with it!

Comment: Thanks, so it’s `flex-direction` as well as `flex-wrap` to reverse both dimensions/directions.